# Determine if the collection {$(a_n : n \in N) : |a_n| = 1$ for all n} is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine if the collection {$(a_n : n \in N) : |a_n| = 1$ for all n} is countable.

Comment: Where are the elements $a_n$ from? If they're from $\mathbb{N}$, then $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, and there's exactly one such sequence. If they're from $\mathbb{R}$, there are a lot more sequences, corresponding to choices of $\pm 1$. If they're from $\mathbb{C}$, there are vastly more sequences.

Comment: I think it is from R, the question did not really specify

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then the set $\{ a_n \}$ may not be countable.  Take the set of all irrational roots of unity, that is, let your set be $\{e^{2 \pi i n \alpha}: \alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $n$, then the mapping $(a_n)\mapsto\{n\in\mathbb N\mid a_n=1\}$ is a bijection between the set of interest and the set $2^\mathbb N$ of subsets of $\mathbb N$. One knows that, for *every* set $A$, the sets $A$ and $2^A$ are not equipotent, hence the set of interest is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $n$, then this set is the collection of sequences whose terms are $\pm 1$. This can be corresponded with the collection of sequences in $0$ and $1$, which can then (via binary expansion) be corresponded with the unit interval.